# Jenkins: Thinbackup Plugin compared to manual backup

Tags: jenkins, backup, jenkins-plugins, disaster-recovery

I'm looking at ways to automatically backup our instance of Jenkins on a regular basis. One of the strategies I've seen for this is using the [thinBackup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/thinBackup).

I've taken a look at the directory containing the backup that thinBackup creates, and it seems to have substantially different directory structure and files than Jenkins home directory does.

**thinBackup backup directory**:

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jun 22 14:57 ./
drwxrwxr-x+ 3 root    root    4096 Jun 22 14:57 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins 3159 Jun 21 17:24 config.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  978 Jun  5 10:10 credentials.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  135 Jun 21 17:24 github-plugin-configuration.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  808 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  159 Jun 22 14:01 hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins 1169 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  320 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  370 May 31 08:51 hudson.plugins.git.GitTool.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  513 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.scm.CVSSCM.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  388 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  188 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.tasks.Mailer.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   76 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.tasks.Shell.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  215 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins 6515 Jun 22 14:57 installedPlugins.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   93 Jun 21 17:17 jenkins.CLI.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  159 Jun 21 17:24 jenkins.model.ArtifactManagerConfiguration.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  138 Jun 21 17:17 jenkins.model.DownloadSettings.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  264 Jun 21 17:24 jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  535 Jun 21 17:24 jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshPublisherPlugin.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  472 Jun 21 17:17 jenkins.security.QueueItemAuthenticatorConfiguration.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  381 Jun 21 17:17 jenkins.security.UpdateSiteWarningsConfiguration.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  630 Jun 21 17:24 jobConfigHistory.xml
drwxr-xr-x  6 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jun 22 14:57 jobs/
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  907 Jun 22 14:01 nodeMonitors.xml
drwxr-xr-x  5 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jun 21 15:20 nodes/
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  270 Jun 21 17:24 org.jenkinsci.plugins.bitbucket_approve.BitbucketApprover.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  290 Jun 21 17:24 org.jenkinsci.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketBuildStatusNotifier.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  290 Jun 21 17:24 org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.config.GlobalConfig.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   46 Jun 21 17:00 org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowExecutionList.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  218 Jun 21 17:24 org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries.xml
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jun 22 14:57 plugins/
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins 1015 Jun 22 14:57 thinBackup.xml
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 25 13:29 userContent/
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jun  5 11:27 users/
```

**Jenkins home directory**:

```
drwxr-xr-x 17 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 22 14:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x 74 root    root        4096 Jun 22 14:17 ../
drwxr-xr-x 31 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 22 14:57 config-history/
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins     3159 Jun 21 17:24 config.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      978 Jun  5 10:10 credentials.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      135 Jun 21 17:24 github-plugin-configuration.xml
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 19 09:20 .groovy/
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      808 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      159 Jun 22 14:01 hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins     1169 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      320 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      370 May 31 08:51 hudson.plugins.git.GitTool.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      513 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.scm.CVSSCM.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      388 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      188 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.tasks.Mailer.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins       76 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.tasks.Shell.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      215 Jun 21 17:24 hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger.xml
-rw-------  1 jenkins jenkins     1712 May 25 13:29 identity.key.enc
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins     4096 May 25 13:28 .java/
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins       93 Jun 21 17:17 jenkins.CLI.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins        6 May 26 09:19 jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins        6 May 25 13:29 jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      159 Jun 21 17:24 jenkins.model.ArtifactManagerConfiguration.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      138 Jun 21 17:17 jenkins.model.DownloadSettings.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      264 Jun 21 17:24 jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      535 Jun 21 17:24 jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshPublisherPlugin.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      472 Jun 21 17:17 jenkins.security.QueueItemAuthenticatorConfiguration.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      381 Jun 21 17:17 jenkins.security.UpdateSiteWarningsConfiguration.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root           0 Jun 22 08:35 jenkins.start
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins 70340821 May 26 09:28 jenkins.war
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      630 Jun 21 17:24 jobConfigHistory.xml
drwxr-xr-x  6 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 19 14:44 jobs/
drwxr-xr-x  4 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 21 15:01 logs/
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      907 Jun 22 14:01 nodeMonitors.xml
drwxr-xr-x  5 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 21 15:20 nodes/
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins     4096 May 25 13:28 .oracle_jre_usage/
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      270 Jun 21 17:24 org.jenkinsci.plugins.bitbucket_approve.BitbucketApprover.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      290 Jun 21 17:24 org.jenkinsci.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketBuildStatusNotifier.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      290 Jun 21 17:24 org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.config.GlobalConfig.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins       46 Jun 21 17:00 org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowExecutionList.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      218 Jun 21 17:24 org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins       54 Jun 22 13:59 .owner
drwxr-xr-x 72 jenkins jenkins    12288 Jun 22 14:01 plugins/
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins      130 Jun 22 14:01 queue.xml.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins       64 May 25 13:28 secret.key
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins        0 May 25 13:28 secret.key.not-so-secret
drwx------  4 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 21 15:01 secrets/
drwx------  2 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun  2 17:21 .ssh/
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins        0 Jun 22 14:58 ThinBackup Worker Thread.log
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins     1015 Jun 22 14:57 thinBackup.xml
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 22 08:36 updates/
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins     4096 May 25 13:29 userContent/
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun  5 11:27 users/
drwxr-xr-x 10 jenkins jenkins     4096 May 26 09:28 war/
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins     4096 Jun 19 09:20 workflow-libs/
```

- Are there any folders / files in Jenkins home directory that the
  thinBackup misses in doing a backup?

I've [read](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216241937-Migrating-Jenkins-instances) that copying Jenkins home directory from one server with Jenkins installed to another server with Jenkins installed is the general process for migrating a Jenkins instance to another server.

- Is it best practice to err on the side of caution and backup the entire Jenkins home directory somewhere?
- If this is the case, what is the best way to automate this process so
  that backups are automatically made on a regular basis?

I want to avoid a situation where an issue occurs and we're missing necessary files to restore the pre-disaster Jenkins instance's configuration.

I'm fairly new to Jenkins administration so any advice, guidance and information is welcome. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

ThinBackup supposedly only saves the minimal amount of necessary files for you to be able to restore your Jenkins configuration (unless you make it store more stuff like user config or build numbers and such). I have been using it for a while and was able to restore my configuration multiple times without noticing anything to be amiss.